# Why __init__ doesn't execute after adding metaclass to a class?

Tags: python, class

For the code below

```py
class C:

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<C {self.data}>'


print(C(30))
print(C('hello, world'))
```

I can get the result

```
<C 30>
<C hello, world>
```

Now I try to add a metaclass to class `C` like below:

```py
class P(type):
    def __call__(cls, data):
        if isinstance(data, int):
            return data
        else:
            return cls.__new__(cls, data)


class C(metaclass=P):
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        return super().__new__(cls)

    def __init__(self, data):
        self.data = data

    def __str__(self):
        return f'<C {self.data}>'


print(C(30))
print(C('hello, world'))
```

This time when execute `print(C('hello, world'))` I get an exception as:

```
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'data'
```

Seems that the `C` object was created but the `__init__` method was skipped. Can anybody tell me why?

Comment: `__init__()` is only executed if `__new__()` returns an instance of the `cls` argument.

Comment: @martineau After add metaclass I add breakpoints to C.__new__ and C.__init__ ， I can see C.__new__ was executed but C.__init__ was not, this confuse me.

Comment: You never call `__init__`. Your metaclass's `__call__` only calls `__new__`.

Comment: My comment explains why `__init__()` may not be executed (even if `__new__()` is).

Comment: @user2357112 You mean I have to explicitly run `__init__` in `P.__call__` ?

Comment: If you want to write your own `__call__`, you have to put in everything you want that `__call__` to do. Python won't insert an `__init__` call for you.